# Eclipse(+AppEngine SDK) & Google "push-to-deploy" GIT repository

Tags: eclipse, git, google-app-engine

Is it possible to use Eclipse (with AppEngine SDK plugin) and Google "push-to-deploy" together? I have managed to install "gcloud"-tools and initialize a project fine! But now I can't figure out how to combine Eclipse project structure and the structure generated by "gcloud init". I mean I would like to do this:

1) Use Eclipse to edit the application and test it locally in Development server as before 
2) But also utilize Google "Push-to-deploy" GIT repository (instead of GitHub)

Is this possible or feasible and is there any instructions how to do this kind of project setup correctly.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: you just need to install git and configure push to deploy settings on your local computer based on the documentation from google

Comment: @MevinBabu Thanks, yes I got GIT working by just copying the .git folder under my Eclipse project folder. I still need to figure out how to deal with different deployment versions etc... It is not necessarily feasible to deploy directly to the default version. Also the Eclipse EGit plugin does not authenticate with Google repository. The command line GIT (Cygwin) works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

After some more experiments with gcloud (Google Cloud SDK) I would recommend creating the project with Maven and use Maven for building & running the development server. Still you can import the Maven project in Eclipse and use that as Java editor + remote debugger. Here's the instruction to get started:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven

Also Google Endpoints is quite nice tool for building REST APIs (though it still has some weaknesses, like limited support for HttpServletRequest data and poor authorization support in Development server)
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/